# Running OP5 Monitor in VM Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, op5

I'm trying to run Op5 Monitor Virtual Appliance in VM Virtual Box but couldn't able to resolve an error! I created a Virtual Machine and tried to add "op5-Monitor-Virtual-Appliance-6.1.1-x86_64-disk1.vmdk" virtual hard disk to the new machine but I'm getting an error like this:

`Failed to open the hard disk file D:\op5-Monitor-Virtual-Appliance-6.1.1-x86_64\op5-Monitor-Virtual-Appliance-6.1.1-x86_64-disk1.vmdk.
Could not get the storage format of the medium 'D:\op5-Monitor-Virtual-Appliance-6.1.1-x86_64\op5-Monitor-Virtual-Appliance-6.1.1-x86_64-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import (File->Import) the OVF file. This will import the entire virtual machine, there is no need to create your own virtual machine.

I'd also recommend that you use a newer version - 6.1.3 and 6.2.0 have been released.

Best regards
Mikael Falkvidd
op5 Development team lead